# Cordova AngularJS $http.post Browser CORS Issue - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin"

Tags: php, angularjs, post, cross-domain, cors

Hope this helps someone else out there (as it took me hours to find a fix).

*** Yes there are many duplicate similar questions out there, that are similar - But mine is specific to a Cordova platform Browser app. ***

I am building an with AngularJS using Cordova/PhoneGap. I had a cross domain issue while making a AngularJS POST request (`$http.post`) to a PHP API. If was returning - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin"

Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I Had to add the following to the PHP API script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Now after doing an `$http.post` it will return status code 200!